# MongoDB collection hyphenated name

Tags: mongodb, collections

I'm using Node.js program to insert data into a MongoDB database. I have inserted data into a collection named "repl-failOver".

```
var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:30002/test", function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    db.collection("repl-failOver").insert( { "documentNumber" : document++}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(doc);
    });
    db.close();
});
```

When I use the Mongo shell and list down the collections in the database using `show collections` I am able to see the collection "repl-failOver".

How do I run a find command from the mongo shell for this collection?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
db['repl-failOver'].find({})
```

or

```
db.getCollection('repl-failOver').find({})
```

You can find more information in the [Executing Queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/#executing-queries) section of the manual:

> If the mongo shell does not accept the name of the collection, for
>   instance if the name contains a space, hyphen, or starts with a
>   number, you can use an alternate syntax to refer to the collection, as
>   in the following:
>
> ```
> db["3test"].find()
>
> db.getCollection("3test").find()
> ```

Comment: First option doesn't work with MongoDB 3.4. Second one is wroks! Thx

Answer (score 7):

You are getting this error from accessing collections with specific characters (`-`, `_`, ). I explained the workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13662012/1090562), but basically all you need is to do

`db.getCollection("repl-failOver").insert(...)`