# MongoDB shell (mongo) not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have `mongod` running with the following command:

```
$ mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
```

The documents were inserted OK with this script:

**insert.js**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/edx-course-db';

MongoClient.connect(url, (error, client) => {
  if (error) return process.exit(1);

  console.log('Connection is OK');
  var db = client.db('mytestingdb');  
  var collection = db.collection('edx-course-students');

  collection.insert([
    {name : 'Bob'}, {name : 'John'}, {name : 'Peter'}
  ], (error, result) => {
    if (error) { 
      console.log('error in insert');
      return process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('result.result.n :' + result.result.n);
    console.log('result.ops.length: ' + result.ops.length);
    console.log('Inserted 3 documents into the edx-course-students collection');
  });
  client.close();
})
```

This is the output:

```
$ node insert.js                                                          
Connection is OK
result.result.n :3
result.ops.length: 3
Inserted 3 documents into the edx-course-students collection
```

And I run the `find` method, the documents are shown (that is how I know the insert worked fine):

**find.js**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/edx-course-db';

MongoClient.connect(url, (error, client) => {
  if (error) return process.exit(1);

  console.log('Connection is OK');
  var db = client.db('mytestingdb');  
  var collection = db.collection('edx-course-students');

  collection.find({}).toArray((error, docs) => {
    if (error) return process.exit(1);
    console.log(`docs.length: ${docs.length}`);
    console.log(`Found the following documents:`);
    console.dir(docs);
  });
  client.close();
});
```

This is the output:

```
$ node find.js 
Connection is OK
docs.length: 3
Found the following documents:
[ { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] },
    name: 'Bob' },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] },
    name: 'John' },
  { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] },
    name: 'Peter' } ]
```

**The problem is that I can't see the documents in the MongoDB shell**, I've tried this:

Connecting to MongoDB shell with:

```
$ mongo
```

Inside MongoDB shell I can see my database (mytestingdb):

```
> show dbs
blog         0.031GB
local        0.078GB
mytestingdb  0.031GB
test         0.078GB
```

And change to my desire db:

```
> use mytestingdb
switched to db mytestingdb
```

I can see my collection (edx-course-students):

```
> show collections
edx-course-students
system.indexes
```

But no documents are shown with `find()`, and `count()` returns 0:

```
> db.collection.find({});
> db.collection.count();
0
```

**Note**: If I delete mytestingdb with `dropDatabase()`, like this:

```
> db.dropDatabase();
{ "dropped" : "mytestingdb", "ok" : 1 }
```

the **find.js** no longer shows the documents (so I'm sure the insert, find and the shell commands are pointing to the same db).

This are my versions:

```
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.6.1

$ mongod --version
db version v3.0.15

$ node --version
v8.9.1
```

What am I missing here? There is something wrong with my shell commands?

If any relevant information is missing, please let me know.

Comment: Refer to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711939/mongodb-collection-hyphenated-name)

Comment: Where did you saved these js files to be able to run them in mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta replace the `collection` by the name of the collection you want to perform the request on.Plus change the name of your collection, it would be invalid to request it that way (with - separators).

```
db.edx.course.students.find({});
```

Look at [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: Thank you @Grégory NEUT, I've already tried that, and it gives me this error: `2018-01-05T14:58:04.552+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: course is not defined :
@(shell):1:1`

Comment: OK so that means you cannot put `-` in collections names. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868323/is-there-a-convention-to-name-collection-in-mongodb)

Comment: Really?? That is so logical!! let my try that and I will tell you how it goes.

Comment: You were correct, the problem is the `-` in the name of the collection, I've replaced `'edx-course-students'` with `'students'` and now `db.students.find({});` is showing all the documents. Thank you very much Monsieur.